# Boolean difference removes wrong part

Tags: modifiers

I have a cube that is scaled about 10 times on the Z axis.
I added a plane, rotated it 45 degrees on the Y axis, and placed it just below the top of the cube. I applied a boolean difference modifier to the cube, and it cut off the bottom. How can I invert the boolean operation to cut off the top of the cube instead? The plane should be deleted after the cutting.

[image: Plane and cube shown without boolean modifier]

[image: Plane and cube shown with boolean modifier cutting off the wrong part of cube]

Comment: it depends on the face normals, flip the plane 180° and try again

Comment: You can flip normals on the plane to fix that.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50632/1853

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Boolean modifier calculations depends on the face normals to decide what's inside and outside ; for a simple plane case the face normal is the local z_axis so it's enough to flip the plane 180°

for other case :

- enter edit mode hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
- check inside option on the tools panel

Comment: Also note that you can use `Ctrl Shift N` to enable the *inside* option without an extra step

Answer (score 4):

you can use a different kind of operation on the boolean  modifier for different results:
[image]